# LDAP: forced to change root password on every login

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, pam, pam-ldap

I have finally configured my new server as LDAP-client of my existing one. Now, every time I login as root, I am prompted to change my 'LDAP password':

```
login as: root
root@111.111.111.111's password:
You are required to change your LDAP password immediately.
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab090.3 i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Fri Jul  4 15:45:24 2014 from xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.de
Changing password for root.
(current) UNIX password:
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
root@ubuntuserver:~#
```

I disabled LDAP authentification using "pam-auth-update --force", but I still get the same prompt on every root-login. My "/val/log/auth.log" is completeley empty. How can I get rid of this prompt (preferably with LDAP enabled again)?

Comment: can you show "grep ldap /etc/pam.d/*passwd*" ?

Comment: returns nothing...  but I have resolved the problem myself. I have a user root in my LDAP (does it belong there ?). I deleted this user and recreated it again, and now everything seems to work. I am still wondering why I got the above behaviour while not connected to LDAP...

Comment: did you check your /etc/nsswitch.conf?